# What is the difference between auth0 and Google Identity Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, auth0

What is the difference between auth0 and Google Identity Platform?

In terms of the service they offer, is it the same?

Answer (score -6):

Identity Platform is a Google Cloud service, whereas "auth0" is a product from another company, so they are distinct products.

You can find information about Identity Platform at [1](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs) [2](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/concepts-authentication) for its functionalities.

Comment: I mean, they both seem to offer the same service. Right?

Comment: Hi,

You can see a description on Google Identity Platform [1] and auth0 [2] on GCP Documentation.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform
[2] https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method#auth0